# How to load file in object context

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I'm playing with some meta-programming concepts and wonder if something I want to do is simply possible.

There's simple DLS for events,

```
//test_events.rb
event 'monthly events are suspiciously high' do
  true
end
```

and the script should shout out when event returns true, I try to do this without polluting global namespace with method event, and any instance variables. So I try something like this:

```
Dir.glob('*_events.rb').each do |file|

  MyClass = Class.new do
    define_method :event do |name, &block|
      @events[name] = block
    end
  end

  env = MyClass.new

  env.instance_eval{@events = {}}

  env.instance_eval{load(file)}

end
```

So for each *_events.rb file I would like to load it in context of MyClass (i know that with 2nd loop of Dir.glob#each it will complain about already defined const - not important now).

The problem is with `env.instance_eval{load(file)}` code in test_events.rb is run in Object context, because I get

```
undefined method `event' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Is there a way to do it? ( I try now in 1.9.3 but changing version up is not a problem since it's just exercise)

Comment: You might want to look at this blogpost for a walkthrough on how to create a custom DSL in ruby: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/writing-a-domain-specific-language-in-ruby

Comment: Thanks, this is really interesting read. Nevertheless I failed to find an answer to my question. The thing is I know ho to make a DSL which would work like this: `Redflag.register do
  event 'monthly events are suspiciously high' do
    true
  end
end
` this is fairly easy. But let me rephrase my question: how to call Kernel#load in context of any object instance. From all my attempts it looks like it will always be called in top-object Object context. Is it possible?

Comment: AFAIK no, `load` is not context sensitive - it loads the code to the global scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`instance_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) can take a `String` as its argument instead of a block, so rather than [`load`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-load) (which as you suggest will load the file in the top level) you need to read the file contents into a string to pass in, something like:

```
env.instance_eval(File.read(file))
```